# Execute Terminal Command in Linux Kernel Hook

Tags: shell, kernel-modules, netfilter

How do I execute the following command from a loadable Linux kernel hook:

```
echo 5 > /sys/kernel/debug/ieee80211/phy0/ath9k/AggregationLimit
```

Answer (score 0):

According to *[22.5. Setting Module Parameters](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Setting_Module_Parameters.html)* (Fedora, and also [Red Hat Enterprise](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Setting_Module_Parameters.html)):

> Because parameters *cannot* be dynamically set for a module that is already loaded into a running kernel, there are two different methods for setting them.

and it goes on to describe how to reload a module, setting the desired parameters using `modprobe`.

According to *[/proc/sys vs /sys/modules/mod/parameter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89017/proc-sys-vs-sys-modules-mod-parameter)* answer by Gilles (but lacking a suitable source):

> You can read, and sometimes modify, the parameters of the module *foo* by writing to `/sys/module/foo/parameters/*`.

but he adds:

> Components that are loaded in the kernel read their parameters from the kernel command line. These parameters cannot be set at runtime (at least not through an automatically-generated interface like `/sys/module`: the component can expose a custom interface for this).

so unless your component provides an interface, (re)loading the module with the desired parameters sounds like the way to approach the problem.